# Django related model, create if does not exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I have the following models:

```
class Merchant(BaseModel):
    user = OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='merchant', primary_key=True)

class MerchantExtended(BaseModel):
    merchant = OneToOneField(Merchant, related_name='extended', primary_key=True)
    billing_address = TextField()
```

And when saving a form containing Merchant and MerchantExtended data I would like to be able to do:

```
user = get_user_from_somewhere()
merchant = Merchant(user=user)

# Implicitly does get_or_create() and sets merchant.extended.merchant
merchant.extended.billing_address = '123 Main St'

# Implicitly does merchant.extended.save()
merchant.save()
```

Is the above something which already exists, or do I need to override certain model properties/methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I think Django's [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) can be used here:

```
merchant = Merchant.objects.get(user=request.user)
ext_merchant, created = MerchantExtended.objects.update_or_create(
    merchant=merchant, defaults={'billing_address': '123 Main St'}
)
```